# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'onClickable' in package 'android'

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am facing error on click event. I have put code mention below,

```
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/switchy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#C0000000"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:onClickable="true"
        android:onClick="Clicked"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Switch"/>
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:onClickable="true"` with `android:enabled="true"`. `android:onClickable` does not exists

Answer (score 0):

onClickable does not exist. You confused OnClick with Clickable, resulting in OnClickable :)

Change it to

> clickable="true"

for the onClick to be called.